# Swashbuckle root error when i deploy on subfolder

Tags: api, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I begin with Swashbuckle, i make a Web API in .NET Core with Swashbuckle.
I need to deploy my API in a sub-application of an IIS site

### IIS infrastructure

- IIS Site (site)

  - myApi (subApplication)

  http://ip:80/myApi

I would like the access to swagger UI to be done via this url :

```
http://ip:80/myApi/swagger
```

I would like the access to the methods to be done by this url :

```
http://ip:80/myApi/api/[controller]/methode
```

### ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.Info { Title = "My REST API", Version = "v1" });
        });
```

### Configure(IApplicationBuilder app..)

```
if (env.IsEnvironment("ProdIT"))
        {
            app.UseSwagger(c =>
            {

                c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.BasePath = "/myApi/");
                c.RouteTemplate = "myApi/api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
            });
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.RoutePrefix = "myApi/swagger";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/myApi/api-docs/v1/swagger.json", "MY REST API V1");});
```

### Route Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by configuring the SwaggerUI like that;

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
     c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "MY REST API V1");});
}
```

Comment: Ok, with this endpoint and i update swashbuckle from 2.3 to 2.5 it's work